# Is there a GUI tool help to create gui xml

Tags: android

I am new to android.
As I know, an android app used xml to construct the gui.
Is there a tool to create the gui xml from a visual drag & drop editor?

Comment: http://www.droiddraw.org/ as mentioned its not so great with relative layou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go with [Google App Inventor](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/about/index.html).

Comment: The link is dead. The App Inventor project was cancelled, but the source code is now freely available at http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-releases/

Answer (score 0):

App Inventor only output .apk file. Is there a way to output the XML layout?

DroidDraw you give some help. But not quite easy to use. It can only produce some basic structure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the gui builder in eclipse, which is useful in a few cases.  Although, your better of just making the XML yourself, and doing the fine tweaking in the gui editor.

There is droid draw, but from my experience with relative layouts it fails to properly build the xml.

There is also app inventor, but I haven't tried it though so I don't know how well it works.

If your looking for something that is as nice as the iPhone's gui builder, from my experience anyway, your out of luck.  Roll up your sleeves and start hacking out xml.  (Or java code if you want to write 10x as much).  Sorry to have to tell you that.